# What is wrong with my potted mango tree?

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-health

I started growing these in 2016. 
One is doing good but growing very slowly. The other one grew fast but now the leaves at the top are dying but yet at the bottom, new branches are growing. 
I live in Miami, FL and they get direct sun daily since I'm facing the east.

http://i16.photobucket.com/albums/b50/yasmel/20180421_172311_zpsqnxcbu0r.jpg

http://i16.photobucket.com/albums/b50/yasmel/20180421_172825_zpsau8ju39z.jpg

http://i16.photobucket.com/albums/b50/yasmel/20180421_171727_zpsm1usku87.jpg

Comment: We are looking at two different plants, yes?  What do you mean they get direct sun?  From an east facing window?  Do you ever take them out of doors on the patio?  Do you have a covered patio?  Don't ever put them in the sun out of doors unless acclimated...and if you have a covered patio no direct sun that would be a good place for them to get more light, but no direct sun light out of doors.  Next, have you ever given these plants fertilizer?  That is what I am seeing, lack of chemistry so these plants are able to make their own food for energy.  Photosynthesis is how plants make their own~

Comment: ...food, energy, chemistry to do repairs...fertilizer is not food.  But it is essential for plants to make their own food.  Too little, unbalanced is a slow death and just a little too much can be a fast death.  Your plants look like they are dying the slow death of no fertilizer/chemistry added to their potting soil.  Osmocote 14-14-14 would be the safest bet if you aren't using any other type of fertilizer.  The leaves growing at the base of the one plant are purple...a sure fire indication there is no phosphorus in that soil.  Have you ever fertilized?

Comment: Thank you. No, I have never put fertilizer on and yes, they are in my balcony getting direct sunlight. I can move them to another place in the balcony so they don't get sun the whole day.

Comment: If they are used to direct sunlight then you are fine putting them in direct sunlight out of doors.  All plants us humans want to grow...for food, beauty all our endeavors are artificial.  We humans are on call to provide for every need.  Fertilizer is critical...without these chemicals, plants are unable to photosynthesize and make their own food.  I think just some basic BALANCED fertilizer (NPK) will solve your problems.  Just a little...now and then.  Too much and you'll kill your plants.  If your plants are used to the sun then NO problem.  Leave them where they are...

Comment: Thank you. I'll go to Home depot and see if I find a fertilizer.